# JXBrowser: PDF file opened in Jxbrowser can we open external links from inside the PDF?

Tags: java, jxbrowser

JxBrowser: PDF file opened in JxBrowser can we open external links from inside the PDF?
Please suggest how to open external links in JxBrowser.

Comment: An updated build with the fix is available for download from https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.18.1-b10-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently impossible to open external links from inside the PDF. It is an issue in JxBrowser and JxBrowser team is informed about that issue.